# Python : Subtract columns value in ascending order value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Have a dataframe mortgage_data with columns name mortgage_amount and month (in asceding order)

`mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month 
mark     400              1
mark     500              2
mark     200              3
```

How to deduct  and update `mortgage_amount` in ascending order or month using `mortgage_amount_paid` row by row in a dataframe
and add a column `paid_status` as yes if mortgage_amount_paid is fully deducted for that amount and no if not like this

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`
mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status 
mark     400              1         0                     full
mark     500              2         0                     full
mark     200              3       100                     partial
```

ex:

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 600`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status 
mark     400              1         0                     full
mark     500              2       300                     partial
mark     200              3       200                     zero
```

tried this:

```
import numpy as np
mortgage_amount_paid = 1000
df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = np.where(mortgage_amount_paid - df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum() >=0 , 0, df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum() - mortgage_amount_paid)
df['paid_status'] = np.where(df['mortgage_amount_updated'],'full','partial')
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use masks:

```
mortgage_amount_paid = 600

# amount saved - debt
m1 = df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum().sub(mortgage_amount_paid)
# is it positive?
m2 = m1>0
# is the previous month also positive?
m3 = m2.shift(fill_value=False)

df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = (m1.clip(0, mortgage_amount_paid)
                                   .mask(m3, df['mortgage_amount'])
                                 )
df['paid_status'] = np.select([m3, m2], ['zero', 'partial'], 'full')
```

output:

```
   name  mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated paid_status
0  mark              400      1                        0        full
1  mark              500      2                      300     partial
2  mark              200      3                      200        zero
```

Comment: if mortgage_amount_paid=0.

paid_status should be zero,zero,zero. i'm getting partial,zero,zero

Comment: You can probably use `m3 = m2.shift(fill_value=mortgage_amount_paid==0)` (untested)

Comment: i have given mortgage_amount_paid=400 with new changes. 

paid status should be paid,zero,zero.  i'm getting paid,partial,zero

Comment: possible to check ?

Answer (score 1):

Idea is the `cumsum` before `partial` should less than `mortgage_amount_paid` and there could be at most one `partial`

```py
mortgage_amount_paid = 600

m = df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum()

df['paid_status'] = np.select(
    [m <= mortgage_amount_paid,
     (m > mortgage_amount_paid) & (m.shift() < mortgage_amount_paid)
     ],
    ['full', 'partial'],
    default='zero'
)
df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = np.select(
    [df['paid_status'].eq('full'),
     df['paid_status'].eq('partial')],
    [0, m-mortgage_amount_paid],
    default=df['mortgage_amount']
)
```

```
print(df)

   name  mortgage_amount  month paid_status  mortgage_amount_updated
0  mark              400      1        full                        0
1  mark              500      2     partial                      300
2  mark              200      3        zero                      200
```

Comment: if mortgage_amount_paid=1

paid_status should be partial,zero,zero. i'm getting partial zero,zero,zero

Comment: possible to check ?